# differential equation from constants and from the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given a function which has n-constant of the form

$$ y=f(x, c_1, c_2, c_3 ,...........,c_n) $$

is it possible (always) to find the ODE linear or not satisfied by this $ y = f(x) $ so the constants  $ cn$ does not appear

for example $$y =c_1 e^{ix} + c_2 e^{-ix} $$

satisfies the equation $$ y'' +y =0 $$

or for example $ y = sin(x+c_2) $  satisfies the non-linear ODE

$$ (y')^2 +y^{2}=1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual procedure applies, compute $$y^{(k)}=\partial_x^k f(x;c), ~~ k=0,..,n$$ and eliminate the $c$ in a locally unique way.
The remaining equation is an order $n$ equation $$0=F(x,y,y',...,y^{(n)}).$$ This equation is the solvability condition for the overdetermined system of $n+1$ equations for $n$ parameters $c=(c_1,...,c_n)$. In the linear case $y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ this condition can be written as $$0=\det\pmatrix{y&y_1&y_2\\y'&y_1'&y_2'\\y''&y_1''&y_2''}.$$

Comment: Prof. Lutz: The determinant looks like the familiar Wronskian determinant. Can we also state it equivalently as $W(y, y_1, y_2) = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.